# How to change the transition animation of an app?

Tags: html, ionic4, pinterest, uiviewanimationtransition

I am developing an app in ionic 4 and this has a gallery section and that for now gives a user experience that leaves much to be desired.

I would like to change the transition animation of an application to something more similar to Pinterest, does anyone know how to achieve this?

I have found some repositories that achieved this in Swift and objectic C, but they are very old and I cannot make them compile well in the current versions of Xcode, to whom I leave the repositories that I found

https://github.com/xhzengAIB/PinterestAnimator

https://github.com/demonnico/PinterestSwift

I would like to achieve this effect

![Transition app Pinterest]https://camo.githubusercontent.com/fdae059a7511ddab4e3dfdf5337c1ab85f9e60e9/687474703a2f2f692e737461636b2e696d6775722e636f6d2f30666e43642e676966

![Transition app Pinterest]https://raw.githubusercontent.com/demon1105/ImagesLib/master/compressed.gif

My gallery is nothing more than a list of images, which click on them are displayed in a modal.
I can't think of any way to get this effect that I'm looking for.

Galeria:

```
  <div class="pins">
    <div class="pin" *ngFor="let image of images" (click)="openPreview(image)">
      <img [src]="image">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Galeria.page.ts:

```
  openPreview(img) {
    debugger;
    this.modalController.create({
      component:TiendaGaleriaModalPage,
      componentProps:{
        img:img
      }
    }).then(modal=>modal.present())
  }
```

Preview:

```
<ion-slides pager="true" [options]="slideOpts">
    <ion-slide>
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
        <img [src]="img">
      </div>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

Preview.page.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.img=this.navParams.get('img')
  }
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: for now my gallery is nothing more than a list of images, which when clicking shows the image in a modal